# Why does the array printing by not considering the positioin?

Tags: arrays, c

I am triying to find the output but it is not what I expected.
Here is the code.

```
void main(void){
int var[2] = { 1,2 }; 
int car = 0; 
if (car = var[2] - 1) printf("YES"); 

else  printf("NO");
```

I thought that it would print No because var[1] is 2 and 2-1 = 1 != 0. But it always print yes. What happened to this code?

Comment: `if (car == var[1] - 1) ` is what you want. Turn on compiler warnings!

Comment: I rolled the edit back, because it invalidated existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

== means equality, = means assignment.

```
if (car == var[2] - 1) printf("YES");
```

Comment: Review trying to read `var[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

`var[2] - 1` is invalid as `var[2]` does not exist - undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two issues:

1. You are accessing element 2 of `var`, but since arrays are zero-indexed there is no element 2 (only elements 0 and 1). That's undefined behaviour (and probably will use the value in `car` since it's declared after `var`, but don't count on that). You are wanting to compare `var[1] - 1` which is `2 - 1`.
2. You have an assignment in your `if` expression instead of an equality comparison. You will want `==` not `=`.

So, change this:

```
if (car = var[2] - 1) printf("YES");
```

to this:

```
if (car == var[1] - 1) printf("YES");
```

PS: turn on compiler warnings with `-Wall`, it would have told you about both issues.